# Ошибка при подключении к базе SQLite на уровне драйвера

Tags: sqlite

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе SQLite. Ошибка на уровне драйвера. Не понятно куда копать.

```
    public class Main {
        public static final String DB_PATH = "jdbc:sqlite:d:\\SQLite\\DB\\CarShop.db";
        public static final String DRIVER_SQLITE = "org:sqlite:JDBC";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet resultSet = null;

            try {

                Class.forName(DRIVER_SQLITE);


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Драйвер не найден");
            }

        }
```

Вывод в консоль

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=64212:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\JavaBegin\ConnectDB\out\production\ConnectDB;D:\SQLite\jdbc\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4\JavaBegin\ConnectDB\src\com\lib\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" com.company.Main
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org:sqlite:JDBC
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Драйвер не найден

Comment: Разве не `org.sqlite.JDBC`? "Это ведь путь до класса, там двоеточий нет.

Comment: Совершенно верно.